Formulating a solution ansatz for the 1D heat equation in polar coordinates to learn the PDE in a PINN setting
Hello Math Stack Exchange Community,
I am working on solving a partial differential equation (PDE) with a neural network in a PINN-like fashion, and I am seeking advice on identifying an appropriate solution ansatz. The PDE is structured as follows:
$$ \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} - D \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} - \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right) u(t, r) = 0 $$
$$ u(0, r) = u_0(r) $$
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(t, 0) = 0 $$
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t, R) = \frac{D}{J} $$
I want to train a Neural Network that solves the PDE, by incorporating the PDE dynamics into my loss term. These resulting networks are called physics informed in literature. I want my solution to match the temporal and geometric boundaries exactly so I formulate my problem like this.
$$ \hat u(t, r, \theta) =  u_0(r) + A(t,r) \cdot \frac{D}{J} + B(t,r) * NN(t, r,\theta) $$
The idea is that $ A $ and $B$ are chosen is such a way that at the respective points all boundaries are respected, leaving the neural networks to fit only to the dynamic of the PDE itself.
This was also done in other work in this field, for example in Equation 7 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.07871.
However, I struggle to find a correct ansatz. Mind you, I am not a mathematician by trade. I also fail to understand how that paper came to its ansatz. I already tried some implementations with $ A(t,r) = t $ for example and also looked at approximating a Dirac-Impulse. But I could not wrap my head around it, and my ideas don't lead to good results after training.

what is the expression of 'B'? B = tanh(k x)?

No, the activation function is already in $NN(t,r,\theta)$.

That's not what I meant. The equation 10 and 'tanh'  in front of 'NN' in this paper is what I'm referring to.

Ah sorry for misunderstanding, in the paper at Eq10 their solution ansatz defines $B=tanh(\omega x)$ correct. But that does not really work for my PDE problem.
